# How do I copy a directory from one container to another container in Docker Compose?

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have two docker-compose services `nginx` and `django`, and in my `command` shell script I perform a gulp task which builds my static files. After the build process is complete, I want to perform a copy command to copy those files to the nginx container, but I'm not sure what command to use.

### docker-compose.yml

```
django:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile
  user: django
  depends_on:
    - postgres
    - redis
  command: /gunicorn.sh
  env_file: .env

nginx:
  build: ./compose/nginx
  depends_on:
    - django

  ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
```

### gunicorn.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
gulp build
python manage.py migrate
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir=/app
```

I'm guessing I could use scp within `gunicorn.sh`, but i'm not sure how I would reference the `nginx` service's IP address.

Comment: Why be complex about it? Just add the nginx to the django. One container and no worrying about syncing. Or you could have a volume (non-shared) for both

Comment: @ShawnC. Good question. I started with [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django), so I'm just rolling with what they gave me, but I might simplify it to one container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [share volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes-volumedriver) between containers, there is no need to actually copy the files.

There are multiple ways to define the volumes, but I suppose you don't want these files to be on your host file system.

Try something like the following:

```
volumes:
  - static:

django:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile
  user: django
  depends_on:
    - postgres
    - redis
  command: /gunicorn.sh
  volumes:
    - static:/path/to/your/static/files
  env_file: .env

nginx:
  build: ./compose/nginx
  depends_on:
    - django
  volumes:
    - static:/some/dir/to/serve/files/from/
  ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
```

And then configure nginx to serve your static files from `/some/dir/to/serve/files/from/`.

Comment: i tried adding a Data Volume for my static files in my docker-compose setup, but when gulp tries to write (mkdir) in the dest folder, I get `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/powerschool_apps/static/public/css'`. How can I ensure that my data volume permissions are correct?

Comment: You will have to make UIDs among the users that try to write to the volume match. That's the only thing that matters.

Comment: Basically it's just a trade-off between security and portability. You either setup non-root users in your containers, or use root accounts in your containers. In first case you sacrifice portability with the risk for UIDs to mismatch, in second case you give more options for the potential attacker if he somehow gets into the container with one of the exposed services. Relevant discussion: https://forums.docker.com/t/root-user-or-non-root-user-inside-container/966/10

Comment: What I ended up having to do is add `RUN chown django:django /path/to/your/static/files` in my django Dockerfile.